# Sending Variables to Ionic provider from html to generate json from a http.get source

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to send two variables `{{cat_id}}` and `{{gender_id}}` from ionic html to ionic provider and generate json data based on those variables.

**home.html**

```
<button ion-button block *ngFor="let location of allLocation" (click)="gotoMarket(location, cat_id, gender_id)">
                {{location.name}}
</button>
```

**market.ts** -- Provider

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MarketProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello MarketProvider Provider');
  }    
  getMarket(){
    return this.http.get<any[]>('https://idea.com/fetchMarket.php')
  }    
}
```

**fetchMarket.php**

```
$mysqli =mysqli_connect("idea.mysql.com", "idea", "idea@123", "idea");

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

$query = "SELECT * FROM market";
$dbresult = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $dbresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row['mar_id'],
        'name' => $row['mar_name'],
    );
}     
if($dbresult){
    $result = json_encode($data);             
}
else {
    $result = "{'success':false}";
}    
echo $result;
```

I know how to send variable to php `https://idea.com/fetchMarket.php?cat_id=$cat_id&gender_id=$gender_id`

Now i want to know that how to do that in ionic to send the variables to provider and then to the http.get source **(here: https://idea.com/fetchMarket.php)** and make that php file to generate json data based on that variables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is as below:

In market pages folder in market.ts (component ts page) I added this `.filter(allMarket => allMarket.cat_id=== this.cat_id).filter(allMarket => allMarket.gender_id=== gender_id)`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MarketProvider} from '../../providers/market/market';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-market',
  templateUrl: 'market.html',
})
export class MarketPage {

  public allMarket = [];

  cat_id: string;
  gender_id: string;

  constructor(private Market : MarketProvider, public LoadingController : LoadingController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.cat_id = navParams.get('cat_id');
    this.gender_id= navParams.get('gender_id');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let allDataLoadingController = this.LoadingController.create({
        content: "Please Wait"
    });
    allDataLoadingController.present();

    this.Market.getMarket()
    .subscribe((response)=>{allDataLoadingController.dismiss();
    this.allMarket = response.filter(allMarket => allMarket.cat_id=== this.cat_id).filter(allMarket => allMarket.gender_id=== gender_id)});
  }
}
```

Now it filters the json result based on specific variable.

**NOTE**
This solution is through the ionic component page and not based on the source integration page.